# Solving a minimization of the minimum problem

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

> Let ${\bf c}_{1}$, ${\bf c}_{2}\in \mathbb{R}^{n}$, ${\bf A}\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ and ${\bf b}\in\mathbb{R}^{m}$.
>
> Show how one can solve the optimization problem:
>
> > > min $\,$ min$\left({\bf c}^{T}_{1}{\bf x}\,,\, {\bf c}^{T}_{2}{\bf x}\right)$
> > >
> > > $\,\,$s.t. $\,\,\,\,$ ${\bf Ax=b}$
> > >
> > > $\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,$ ${\bf x\ge 0}$

If this were a minimizing the maximum problem, I would have defined a free variable to address the maximum and then the objective would just be minimizing the new free variable.

However, I can't do the same for this. So how should I approach this problem?

Comment: I don't understand how you have two minimums here. Presumably the first is over all ${\bf x}$ and then the second is over what? Also, is that the Euclidean inner product you have there?

Comment: It means minimizing the smaller of the two expressions. No inner product is involved.

Comment: Are you also looking for a minimum in absolute value? I.e. $\min\min(|c^T_1x|,|c^T_2x|)$?

Comment: @ellya Don't think so, the question did not include the absolute values.

Comment: Minimum commutes with itself, so can't you just solve the two problems $\min_x c_1^T x$ and $\min_x c_2^T x$ and see which is lesser?

Comment: @StevenTaschuk That should be correct. Thnx..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a linear programming problem, so it only has one optimal solution. If $c_1$ and $c_2$ are fixed, then just solve them separately to get the minimum one as your solution.

If $c_1$ and $c_2$ is not fixed, I think your question is

$min: c^Tx\\
 s.t. Ax=b\\
      x\geq0\\
      c\in R^n$

Assume there exists $x$ satisfies $Ax=b, \ x\geq0$, then we can always find a $c$ to make the objective function smaller. Therefore, the minimum of this problem is $-\infty$.